# How do I add multiple values to a column in SQL which already has other rows filled

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update this table (name: sports_club):

```
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | name      | sport_interest |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  7 | Winston   | NULL           |
|  8 | Winnefer  | NULL           |
|  9 | Winsteen  | NULL           |
| 10 | Wincifer  | NULL           |
| 11 | Winster   | NULL           |
| 12 | Winstonia | NULL           |
| 13 | Wilson    | NULL           |
| 14 | Winnerva  | NULL           |
| 15 | WinDiesel | NULL           |
+----+-----------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to add values to just the sport_interest column of the existing records, I tried to do that by using:

```
insert into sport_interest values ('cricket'), ('football'), etc.
```

But it did not work as it was trying to add it to new records which I don't want to do.
I'm using MySQL

Comment: You need to use `UPDATE` to update existing rows. https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_update.asp

Comment: `UPDATE sports_club SET sport_interest = "whatever"` will do the trick. :) Using also `WHERE` might specify which records (rows) to be updated.

Comment: @mitkosoft but how do I seamlessly do it uniquely for each record?

Comment: How do you decide which row to have what value? E.g. which is Winstonia's interest?

Comment: Do you have the `id` for the data which you are trying to update ?

Comment: @jarlh I'm assuming the records in SQL to be ordered, I'm not sure if I'm right, I'm very much new to SQL. I thought I can just supply a bunch of values to be added to the column in order

Comment: @Draculin, if you specify the logic of how you want all those records to be updated, we might be able to give you more details.

Comment: Don't depend on rows to be ordered...

Comment: Maybe follow the complete [w3schools MySQL course](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_sql.asp) or would that not hold enough info for this basic SQL questions?

Comment: @Luuk I'm sorry I haven't done the entire course yet, I was just trying to use whatever knowledge I had to create some stuff, apparently I need to do more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the updates manually like:

```
update sport_interest set sport_interest = 'cricket' where id=7;
update sport_interest set sport_interest = 'football' where id=8;
```

And so on...

But, if you have the `id` of the values that you need to update it is much easier.

You can create another table like:

```
create table sport_interest_bak (
id int ,
sport_interest varchar(50));
```

You can use [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) to insert the data on the new table and then update using inner join, it is simpler and much faster.

```
update sport_interest s
inner join sport_interest_bak sb on s.id=sb.id
set s.sport_interest=sb.sport_interest;
```

I suggest reading https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/ or https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/index.php this are much better than W3Schools

Answer (score 0):

Use the '**Update**' command for existing entries.

```
"UPDATE table  SET sport_interest = 'football'" should work.
```

Use WHERE clause if you did not want all cells to update.  ex.

```
UPDATE table  SET sport_interest = 'football' WHERE name = 'Winston'
```

Comment: using the id will be better as there can be multiple cites with the same name in the table, with your approach it will update all rows of a city